# $M \rightarrow M^T M$ is a continuous mapping.

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity

Consider the following mapping over $n \times n$ matrices $$f:M \rightarrow M^T M$$.

My teacher took for granted that it is continous. Intuituively, I'd say that $f$ is a polynomial with the entries of $M$ as variables. That doesn't sound rigorous enough. 
Note that this is unfortunately not a linear mapping.

I failed finding a proof with $\epsilon$ (I think an operator norm fit best this problem).

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Your idea about the entries being (quadratic) expressions in the entries of $M$ works perfectly well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your first intuition is good: The map f is really polynomial with the entries of $M$ as variables!

I mean, you speak of continuity, right? With respect to which topology? I assume that you are using the identification of the space of $n\times n$ matrices with $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ (if using $\mathbb R$ as coefficient). Therefore the variables are the entries of $M$ and in such coordinates $f$ is polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

You talking matrices with entries in $ℝ$ here, right? Then the usual topology of the space $E = \mathrm{Mat}_{n,n} (ℝ)$ of all square matrices is the same as the topology induced by an abovious linear isomorphism $α$ for $E \cong ℝ^{n×n} \cong ℝ^{n^2}$. In other words, such an $α$ defines a homeomorphism.

Therefore, to show that a map $f \colon E → E$ is continuous, it suffices to show that $E \overset{f}{→} E \overset{α}{→} ℝ^{n^2} \overset{π_i}{→} ℝ$ is continuous for all $i = 1, …, n^2$, where $π_i$ denotes the projection to the $i$-th coordinate. Then it would follow that $α ∘ f$ is continuous and so would be $f = α^{-1} ∘ α ∘ f$. So your idea works. In your case $π_i ∘ α ∘ f$ is looking at the $i$-th entry (for some enumeration $i = 1, …, n^2$ of the entries).

Answer (score 1):

Both functions *transposition*
$$t :M \mapsto M^T$$
and *matrix multiplication*
$$m: (A,B) \mapsto AB$$
are continuous, indeed $t$ is just a permutation of variables, and the only operations involved to compute $m$ are scalar multiplication and sums, that are continuous.

Thus 
$$f = m \circ (t,id)$$ 
is continuous, where of course $id(A) = A$ :)

Comment: I like this approach!

Comment: I don't know what level of detail you were asking, but  split a function into the composition of simpler ones is usually a good approach ;)

Answer (score 0):

hint: you can consider this mapping between two manifolds of dimension $n^2$, there is more general definition for "continuous".